# Copy pixels from two image to new matrix in the same size and Undefined function or variable

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote a function that takes an RGB image and a gray image and a new matrix, each time takes the pixels from the RGB image or the gray image and copies it to the new matrix.

At first, I divide the image into rows and columns according to the input of the function.
After that I take the image from the input once in gray and once as RGB and also create a new matrix the same size of the image I received.
Whenever my counter is equal I want to copy the pixels from my gray image into the same square marked in the new matrix and when the counter is not equal then copy the pixels from the RGB image.

I receive the following error message: `Undefined function or variable 'k'`.

how can i fix the function?

i find the error in  resultImg(k,z,d) = rgbEvenPlace(k,z,d); line 
this the message i get: 
    Index in position 2 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or 
    logical values.

how i fix that?

my function:

```
function [rgbToGray] = create_plot(rgbImg,inputRows,inputColmuns)
% each even index replace to gray color
rgbEvenPlace = rgbImg;
rgbToGrayImg = rgb2gray(rgbImg);

[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(rgbEvenPlace);
resultImg = zeros(rows, columns,numberOfColorChannels);
numOfRow = rows / inputRows;
numOfCol = columns / inputColmuns;

counter = 1;
for i = 1 : numOfRow : rows
    for j = 1 : numOfCol : columns
        if mod(counter,2) == 0
           for k=i:numOfRow + i
                for z=j:numOfCol + j
                    for d=1:3
                        resultImg(k,z,d) = rgbEvenPlace(k,z,d); **Error is 
here**
                    end
                end
           end
        else
            for r=1+i:numOfRow+i
                for t=1+j:numOfCol+j                   
                        for d=1:3
                        resultImg(r,t,d) = rgbToGrayImg(r,t,1);     
                    end                  
                end
            end
           imshow(resultImg);
        end
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end   
figure, imshow(resultImg);

% set lines on image
for row = 1 : numOfRow : rows
  line([1, columns], [row, row], 'Color', 'w');
end
for col = 1 : numOfCol : columns
  line([col, col], [1, rows], 'Color', 'w');
end

% save image
saveas(gcf,'moto.jpg');
end
```

thank's

Answer (score 0):

you start with `counter=1` so `if mod(counter ,2) == 0` is not the case. You dont go into the `for k` part but to the `else resultImg(k,z) = rgbToGrayImg(k,z);` part. Here you need k which has never been set.

you can set `k=1` next to `counter=1` to solve this issue